# How to use Beam SQL to perform Lookups

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Is it possible to perform column based lookups using Beam SQL? I have come across a class `BeamJoinTransforms.JoinAsLookup` but couldn't find any working snippet.
Currently, in order to perform Lookups in Apache Beam codes, I'm following a practice to perform 'Left join' using CoGroupByKey/SideInput and produce the filtered TableRows by maintaining a column mapping within my code.
I believe this can be made possible using Beam SQL as well but following a more efficient way to deal with Lookups. Does anyone have any working snippet for this? Looking for examples wherein I could convert `PCollection<TableRow>` to `Pcollection<Row>` and perform the field lookups using Beam SQL library.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's any concrete version of this logic bundled with Beam SDK. It is supposed to be triggered when one of the tables in join is an instance of `BeamSeekableTable`, see [this part](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/9319ce18ac625b239c8cdc1b32e2b697d83c2504/sdks/java/extensions/sql/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/sql/impl/rel/BeamJoinRel.java#L148) of the source code. For more context you can read the original pull request that introduced this feature: [PR-4196](https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/4196)

Currently though, `BeamSeekableTable` doesn't have any working implementations in Beam SDK yet. Potentially you can implement your own `TableProvider` that returns a `BeamSqlTable` implementing that `BeamSeekableTable` as well. For example see [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/06128f27d1780f25c23ca65cc7ace693a78dac80/sdks/java/extensions/sql/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/sql/meta/provider/text/TextTableProvider.java#L70) how `TableProvider` is implemented for [text tables](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/3dd323674fe22cc7e4ea02b151bfb1e565d8943e/sdks/java/extensions/sql/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/sql/meta/provider/text/TextTable.java#L41) (CSV, lines).